# Put the value of an input into another input form in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Having this js fiddle

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('MyController', ['$scope', MyController]);    

function MyController($scope) {

    $scope.value1 = $scope.value1;
    $scope.value2 = "this is it: " + $scope.value1;
}
```

```html
<html>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js">

</script>
<div ng-controller='MyController'>
    <h1>Introduce your value:</h1>
    <input type="text" ng-model="value1"></input></br>
    <input type="text" ng-model="name" ng-change="value1"></input>
</div>
</html>
```

I want to introduce a value in the first input and to get it into the next one as "this is it: firstvalue".

Comment: have you loaded angular.js library in you html?

Comment: @HiteshKansagara sorry, forgot about that. I added it now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve that easily using `ng-change` and using `ng-model` properly

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('MyController', ['$scope', MyController]);    

function MyController($scope) {

    $scope.value1 = undefined;
    $scope.value2 = undefined;
    
    $scope.onValue1Change = function(){
      $scope.value2 = "this is it: " + $scope.value1;
    };
}
```

```html
<html ng-app="myApp">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js">
</script>
<div ng-controller='MyController'>
    <h1>Introduce your value:</h1>
    <input type="text" ng-model="value1" ng-change="onValue1Change()"></input></br>
    <input type="text" ng-model="value2"></input>
</div>
</html>
```